# Is an interface required for recyclerview item click event in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement an `item click event` of a `recyclerview`.

In `Java`, the typical method of creating an `interface` in an `adapter` for clicking an item, implementing it in an `activity`, and passing an `anonymous object` to the `adapter` was used.

However, `Kotlin` accepts `lambda expressions` and can pass them as `arguments`.

So I don't necessarily need to use an `interface`, am I?

Or is there some good reason to use `interfaces` as much as possible?

Comment: Lambda expressions, when used in place of an anonymous object implementing an interface are only syntactic sugar for defining the anonymous object that implements the interface. There's no practical difference, so you might as well use the lambda. Java supports using lambdas for this too if you've set the project to use Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use high-order functions to accomplish that without using interfaces.

Here is an example:

**Fragment/Activity**

```
    recycler_view_photos.adapter = PhotosAdapter {
      actionAfterClickOnItem()
    }

    private fun actionAfterClickOnItem() {
        //stuff
    }
```

**Adapter**

```
class PhotosAdapter(val onItemClicked: () -> Unit) {
  //stuff
  inner class PhotoViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bind(photo: Photo) {
            //stuff
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClicked.invoke()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Interfaces are good to create contracts between components, give a type to a class, and create events, but with Kotlin as you mentioned, you can use lambdas and do the same thing with fewer lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces are best for click listeners in recyclerView like you have views in each view are three buttons like delete, remove and add button so just make three methods in interface

```
fun onDeleteClick(position,Item) //Here item of that model which is passed in adapter
fun onAddClick(position,Item)
fun onRemoveClick(position,Item)
```

implement this interface with your activity and pass it in your adapter and then in your adapter create click listener like this

```
Holder.itemBinding.delete.setOnClickListener{ clickListener.OnDeleteClick(position, Item)  }
```

So instead of passing lambda function for each button just use interface for all clicks and override in your activity